# Typescript Express Request typing

Tags: node.js, typescript, passport.js, passport-jwt

I am having difficulties in typing my request in my express typescript application. I have this controller that is secured using `passport-jwt` so when a route is autheticated I try to access the user data from the `req.user` and that suppose to have a `_id`.

```js
const newPort = { ...req.body, user: req.user?._id };
```

this line produces an error:

```sh
[tsserver 2339] [E] Property '_id' does not exist on type 'User'.
```

How can I fix this one?

Edit: Created a custom type that extends the `Request` Type

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

interface User {
    _id: string,
}

export interface MyRequest extends Request {
    user: User
}

export type MyResponse = Response;
```

Applied it to my controller that manages the API calls

```js
import { IResponse, MyRequest, MyResponse } from '@interface';

export const Create = (req: MyRequest, res: MyResponse): void =>  {
    Rx
        .from(User.Create(req.body))
        .subscribe(
            (result: IResponse) => {
                res.status(result.status).json(result.toJson());
            },
            (error) => {
                res.status(error.status).json(error);
```

But when I call it to my express router. It show an error.

Error:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: can you console log the user data you are picking from within the jwt middleware

Answer (score 2):

You will have to extend the `Request` object to accommodate your custom attributes. For example if your request contains `user` and let's say a tracking id, (most likely by a middleware like passport) create an extended interface like this:

```js
import { Request } from "express";

export interface User {
  _id: string;
  email: string;
}

export interface MyRequest extends Request {
  user?: User;
  trackingId?: string;
}
```

Now, use this new request type everywhere, like this:

```js
app.get('/mypath', (req: MyRequest, res: Response) => {
  const myUserId = req.user?._id;
  ...
});
```

Comment: Hello. But the issue here when I try to use the new type on the routes it give me an error. The `app.use` wants a function that Accepts `Request` and `Response` type

Comment: Could you update the question to show where and how and exact error?

Comment: hmm... looks like they want user to be nullable. Could you try making `user` attribute optional as I have updated in my answer for `MyRequest` interface?

Comment: Hmm I tried the optional and it seems it still produces a new error. Updated my post for the new error